# Source C code of function 'apply'

Tags: help

I referenced `C-h f apply` for the source code of "apply", it prompts

```
References
C code is not yet loaded.
```

but does not hint the destination file.

Execute `grep-find` within Emacs repo thus return no results.

```
find . -type f -exec grep --color -nH --null -e 'int apply' \{\} +
Grep finished with no matches found at Thu Jan 16 18:47:40
```

How could locate the definition of apply in C code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `C-h f` is not the standard `C-h f` (`M-x describe-function`), `describe-function` doesn't provide "References ..." information at all. To find the source of `apply`, use `C-h f apply`, it will say

> apply is a built-in function in `src/eval.c'.

`src/eval.c` will be clickable, then click it to go to the source. If you didn't install Emacs from the source code by yourself, Emacs will ask you to input your "Emacs C source dir", you should enter the path of the Emacs git repo, alternatively, you also can set the variable `source-directory` or `find-function-C-source-directory` in your init file

```el
(setq source-directory "/path/to/your-emacs-repo")

;; OR

(setq find-function-C-source-directory "/path/to/your-emacs-repo/src")
```

> find . -type f -exec grep --color -nH --null -e 'int apply' {} +

We can't know whether `apply` is defined as a plain C function and its return value must be an integer, thus try something different, for example, search `apply` in all *.c files.